# How to extract FlateDecoded Images from PDF with PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

how do I extract Images, which are FlateDecoded (such like PNG) out of a PDF-Document with PDFSharp?

I found that comment in a Sample of PDFSharp:

```
// TODO: You can put the code here that converts vom PDF internal image format to a
// Windows bitmap
// and use GDI+ to save it in PNG format.
// [...]
// Take a look at the file
// PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced/PdfImage.cs to see how we create the PDF image formats.
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks for your replies.

**EDIT:** Because I'm not able to answer on my own Question within 8 hours, I do it on that way:

Thanks for your very fast reply.

I added some Code to the Method "ExportAsPngImage", but I didn't get the wanted results. It is just extracting a few more Images (png) and they don't have the right colors and are distorted.

Here's my actual Code:

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.Filters.FlateDecode flate = new PdfSharp.Pdf.Filters.FlateDecode();
        byte[] decodedBytes = flate.Decode(bytes);

        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat;

        switch (bitsPerComponent)
        {
            case 1:
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed;
                break;
            case 8:
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
                break;
            case 24:
                pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown pixel format " + bitsPerComponent);
        }

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
        var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);
        int length = (int)Math.Ceiling(width * bitsPerComponent / 8.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            int offset = i * length;
            int scanOffset = i * bmpData.Stride;
            Marshal.Copy(decodedBytes, offset, new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + scanOffset), length);
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Export\PdfSharp\" + String.Format("Image{0}.png", count), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            bmp.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

Is that the right way? Or should I choose another way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: With respect to 24 bpp: one format is RGB, the other is BGR. So Marshal.Copy won't do, you have to swap the bytes while you copy. Therefore the wrong colors.
You don't align the BMP data at DWORD boundaries. That should explain the distortion.

Comment: fyi, `bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32()` will fail on 64 bit systems and will need to be changed to ToInt64

Answer (score 6):

I know this answer might be a few years to late, but maybe it will help others.

The disortion occurs in my case because `image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.BitsPerComponent)` seems to not return the correct value. As [Vive la déraison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10024908) pointed out under your question, you get the BGR Format for using `Marshal.Copy`. So reversing the Bytes and rotating the Bitmap after executing `Marshal.Copy` will do the job.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
private static void ExportAsPngImage(PdfDictionary image, ref int count)
    {
        int width = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Width);
        int height = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Height);

        var canUnfilter = image.Stream.TryUnfilter();
        byte[] decodedBytes;

        if (canUnfilter)
        {
            decodedBytes = image.Stream.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            PdfSharp.Pdf.Filters.FlateDecode flate = new PdfSharp.Pdf.Filters.FlateDecode();
            decodedBytes = flate.Decode(image.Stream.Value);
        }

        int bitsPerComponent = 0;
        while (decodedBytes.Length - ((width * height) * bitsPerComponent / 8) != 0)
        {
            bitsPerComponent++;
        }

        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat;
        switch (bitsPerComponent)
        {
            case 1:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed;
                break;
            case 8:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
                break;
            case 16:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555;
                break;
            case 24:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                break;
            case 32:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                break;
            case 64:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown pixel format " + bitsPerComponent);
        }

        decodedBytes = decodedBytes.Reverse().ToArray();

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        int length = (int)Math.Ceiling(width * (bitsPerComponent / 8.0));
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            int offset = i * length;
            int scanOffset = i * bmpData.Stride;
            Marshal.Copy(decodedBytes, offset, new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + scanOffset), length);
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
        bmp.Save(String.Format("exported_Images\\Image{0}.png", count++), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

The code might need some optimisation, but it did export FlateDecoded Images correctly in my case.

Comment: For me, image.Stream.Value returned a byte array where every row of pixels was terminated with a null byte. To output the image from the byte array with extra null bytes, I made the following changes: 
I set `int bitsPerComponent = decodedBytes.Length / height * 8 / width;`. 
I set `int length = decodedBytes.Length / height;`. 
I used `bmpData.Stride` as the length parameter in the `Marshal.Copy` method. 
And it should be `Array.Reverse(decodedBytes);`

Comment: I don't understand the while-loop. What is the logic behind the calculation? In my case the image is 244*244 with 1bps (according to PDF info). Len of decoded data is 7808. First round it increments the bpc to 1. Second round the diff will be 366, so again an increment. From there the diff will constantly increase, leading to an infinite loop. Is something wrong on my part? The decoded data in my case seems to be decoded correctly (I hope).

Comment: The pointer cast was wrong for me. It had to be bmpData.Scan0.ToInt64() !

Answer (score 1):

To get a Windows BMP, you just have to create a Bitmap header and then copy the image data into the bitmap. PDF images are byte aligned (every new line starts on a byte boundary) while Windows BMPs are DWORD aligned (every new line starts on a DWORD boundary (a DWORD is 4 bytes for historical reasons)).
All information you need for the Bitmap header can be found in the filter parameters or can be calculated.

The color palette is another FlateEncoded object in the PDF. You also copy that into the BMP.

This must be done for several formats (1 bit per pixel, 8 bpp, 24 bpp, 32 bpp).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my full code for doing this.

I'm extracting a UPS shipping label from a PDF so I know the format in advance. If your extracted image is of an unknown type then you'll need to check the `bitsPerComponent` and handle it accordingly. I also only handle the first image here on the first page.

Note: I'm using `TryUnfilter` to 'deflate' which uses whatever filter is applied and decodes the data in-place for me. No need to call 'Deflate' explicitly.

```
    var file = @"c:\temp\PackageLabels.pdf";

    var doc = PdfReader.Open(file);
    var page = doc.Pages[0];

    {
        // Get resources dictionary
        PdfDictionary resources = page.Elements.GetDictionary("/Resources");
        if (resources != null)
        {
            // Get external objects dictionary
            PdfDictionary xObjects = resources.Elements.GetDictionary("/XObject");
            if (xObjects != null)
            {
                ICollection<PdfItem> items = xObjects.Elements.Values;

                // Iterate references to external objects
                foreach (PdfItem item in items)
                {
                    PdfReference reference = item as PdfReference;
                    if (reference != null)
                    {
                        PdfDictionary xObject = reference.Value as PdfDictionary;
                        // Is external object an image?
                        if (xObject != null && xObject.Elements.GetString("/Subtype") == "/Image")
                        {
                            // do something with your image here 
                            // only the first image is handled here
                            var bitmap = ExportImage(xObject);
                            bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\exported.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Using these helper functions

```
    private static Bitmap ExportImage(PdfDictionary image)
    {
        string filter = image.Elements.GetName("/Filter");
        switch (filter)
        {
            case "/FlateDecode":
                return ExportAsPngImage(image);

            default:
                throw new ApplicationException(filter + " filter not implemented");
        }
    }

    private static Bitmap ExportAsPngImage(PdfDictionary image)
    {
        int width = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Width);
        int height = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Height);
        int bitsPerComponent = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.BitsPerComponent);   

        var canUnfilter = image.Stream.TryUnfilter();
        var decoded = image.Stream.Value;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        Marshal.Copy(decoded, 0, bmpData.Scan0, decoded.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Images in PDF have byte-aligned rows, Windows Bitmap images have DWORD-aligned rows. In the 8 BPP case it works if the width is a multiple of 4. To support any width, `MarshalCopy` must be called for each row. Thanks for your code - you already mentioned that it is a one-trick horse and not a universal solution.

Comment: It was just frustrating to find the number 1 library couldn't do such a simple thing after years - so once I got the basics working I wanted to share it. Feel free to edit my answer if you improve it

Comment: In my case the TryUnfilter returns false. What can be the reason for it?

Comment: @SaurabhHarwande my guess is that would just mean it doesn't need to be unfiltered, but it wouldn't do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

So far... my code... it works with many `png` files, but not the one that comes from adobe photoshop with colorspace indexed:

```
    private bool ExportAsPngImage(PdfDictionary image, string SaveAsName)
        {
            int width = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfImage.Keys.Width);
            int height = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfImage.Keys.Height);
            int bitsPerComponent = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfImage.Keys.BitsPerComponent);
            var ColorSpace = image.Elements.GetArray(PdfImage.Keys.ColorSpace);
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat= System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb; //24 just for initalize

            if (ColorSpace is null) //no colorspace.. bufferedimage?? is in BGR order instead of RGB so change the byte order. Right now it works
            {
                byte[] origineel_byte_boundary = image.Stream.UnfilteredValue;
                bitsPerComponent = (origineel_byte_boundary.Length) / (width * height);
                switch (bitsPerComponent)
                {
                    case 4:
                        pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                        break;
                    default:
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Unknown pixel format " + bitsPerComponent, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat); //copy raw bytes to "master" bitmap so we are out of pdf format to work with 
                System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(origineel_byte_boundary, 0, bmd.Scan0, origineel_byte_boundary.Length);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
                Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
                for (int indicex = 0; indicex < bmp.Width; indicex++)
                {
                    for (int indicey = 0; indicey < bmp.Height; indicey++)
                    {
                        Color nuevocolor = bmp.GetPixel(indicex, indicey);
                        Color colorintercambiado = Color.FromArgb(nuevocolor.A, nuevocolor.B, nuevocolor.G, nuevocolor.R);
                        bmp2.SetPixel(indicex, indicey, colorintercambiado);
                    }
                }
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(SaveAsName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    bmp2.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                bmp2.Dispose();
                bmp.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
// this is the case of photoshop... work needs to be done here. I ´m able to get the color palette but no idea how to put it back or create the png file... 
                switch (bitsPerComponent)
                {
                    case 4:
                        pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
                        break;
                    default:
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Unknown pixel format " + bitsPerComponent, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                if ((ColorSpace.Elements.GetName(0) == "/Indexed") && (ColorSpace.Elements.GetName(1) == "/DeviceRGB"))
                {
                    //we need to create the palette
                    int paletteColorCount = ColorSpace.Elements.GetInteger(2);
                    List<System.Drawing.Color> paletteList = new List<Color>();
                    //Color[] palette = new Color[paletteColorCount+1]; // no idea why but it seams that there´s always 1 color more. ¿transparency?
                    PdfObject paletteObj = ColorSpace.Elements.GetObject(3);
                    PdfDictionary paletteReference = (PdfDictionary)paletteObj;
                    byte[] palettevalues = paletteReference.Stream.Value;
                    for (int index = 0; index < (paletteColorCount + 1); index++)
                    {
                        //palette[index] = Color.FromArgb(1, palettevalues[(index*3)], palettevalues[(index*3)+1], palettevalues[(index*3)+2]); // RGB
                        paletteList.Add(Color.FromArgb(1, palettevalues[(index * 3)], palettevalues[(index * 3) + 1], palettevalues[(index * 3) + 2])); // RGB
                    }                  
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: that one more color is white which is included by default to show it instead of transparent pixel.

Answer (score 0):

PDF may contain images with masks and with different colorspace options that is why simply decoding an image object may not work properly in some cases.

So the code also needs to check for image masks (/ImageMask) and other properties of image objects (to see if image should also use inverted colors or uses indexed colors) inside PDF to recreate the image similar to how it is displayed in PDF. See Image object, /ImageMask and /Decode dictionaries in the official [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf).

Not sure if PDFSharp is capable of finding Image Mask objects inside PDF but [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com) is able to access image mask objects (see PdfName.MASK object types).

Commercial tools like [PDF Extractor SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/index.html) are able to extract images in both original form and in "as rendered" form.

*I work for ByteScout, maker of PDF Extractor SDK*

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not directly answer the question but another option to extract images from PDF is to use FreeSpire.PDF which can extract the image from pdf easily. It is available as Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.PDF/. They handle all the image format and can export as PNG. Their sample code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using Spire.Pdf;

namespace ExtractImagesFromPDF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiate an object of Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            //Load a PDF file 
            doc.LoadFromFile("sample.pdf");
            List<Image> ListImage = new List<Image>();
            for (int i = 0; i < doc.Pages.Count; i++)
            {
                // Get an object of Spire.Pdf.PdfPageBase
                PdfPageBase page = doc.Pages[i];
                // Extract images from Spire.Pdf.PdfPageBase
                Image[] images = page.ExtractImages();
                if (images != null && images.Length > 0)
                {
                    ListImage.AddRange(images);
                }

            }
            if (ListImage.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListImage.Count; i++)
                {
                    Image image = ListImage[i];
                    image.Save("image" + (i + 1).ToString() + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("image1.png");
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

(code taken from https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/How-to-Extract-Image-From-PDF-in-C.html)