# PNG extracted via from PDF via Flate decoding is unrecognisable - C#

Tags: c#, pdf, png, barcode, decode

The C# software I'm involved with writing has a component that involves the reading of barcodes from scanned documents. The PDFs themselves are opened using [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/).

Unfortunately we're encountering an issue with the process when it involves Flate Decoding of PDFs. Basically, all we get is a bunch of fuzz, which means there is no barcode to check and the document is not recognised.

Our code (which we shamelessly "borrowed" from another Stack Overflow case!) is as follows:

```
private FileInfo ExportAsPngImage(PdfDictionary image, string sourceFileName, ref int count)
    {
        //This code basically comes from http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2338#p6755 
        //and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024908/how-to-extract-flatedecoded-images-from-pdf-with-pdfsharp
        string tempFile = string.Format("{0}_Image{1}.png", sourceFileName, count);

        int width = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Width);
        int height = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Height);
        int bitsPerComponent = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.BitsPerComponent);
        var pixelFormat = new PixelFormat();

        switch (bitsPerComponent)
        {
            case 1:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed;
                break;
            case 8:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
                break;
            case 24:
                pixelFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown pixel format " + bitsPerComponent);
        }

        var fd = new FlateDecode();
        byte[] decodedBytes = fd.Decode(image.Stream.Value);
        byte[] resultBytes = null;
        int newWidth = width;
        int alignment = 4;

        if (newWidth % alignment != 0)
        //Image data in BMP files always starts at a DWORD boundary, in PDF it starts at a BYTE boundary.
        //Most images have a width that is a multiple of 4, so there is no problem with them.
        //You must copy the image data line by line and start each line at the DWORD boundary.
        {
            while (newWidth % alignment != 0)
            {
                newWidth++;
            }

            var copy_dword_boundary = new byte[height, newWidth];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++)
                {
                    if (x <= width && (x + (y * width) < decodedBytes.Length))
                        // while not at end of line, take orignal array
                        copy_dword_boundary[y, x] = decodedBytes[x + (y * width)];
                    else //fill new array with ending 0
                        copy_dword_boundary[y, x] = 0;
                }
            }
            resultBytes = new byte[newWidth * height];

            int counter = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < copy_dword_boundary.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < copy_dword_boundary.GetLength(1); y++)
                {   //put 2dim array back in 1dim array
                    resultBytes[counter] = copy_dword_boundary[x, y];
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            resultBytes = new byte[decodedBytes.Length];
            decodedBytes.CopyTo(resultBytes, 0);
        }

        //Create a new bitmap and shove the bytes into it
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, height, pixelFormat);
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        int length = (int)Math.Ceiling(width * bitsPerComponent / 8.0);

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            int offset = i * length;
            int scanOffset = i * bitmapData.Stride;
            Marshal.Copy(resultBytes, offset, new IntPtr(bitmapData.Scan0.ToInt32() + scanOffset), length);
        }
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        //Now save the bitmap to memory
        using (var fs = new FileStream(String.Format(tempFile, count++), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            bitmap.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        return new FileInfo(tempFile);
    }
```

Unfortunately, all we get out of it is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwatQ.png

Any ideas on where we're going wrong, or suggestions for things we might try would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Don't know what PDFSharp's image's `bitsPerComponent` is, but PDF's `bitsPerComponent` can be 1,2,4,8 (or 16, but it's not your case). You should check `bitsPerComponent` and `ColorSpace` to check all possible variants.

Comment: Hm hah. No idea as yet at what particular point your code fails, but unpacking your "PNG" image shows the `IDAT` contents are in fact raw JPEG bytes. Unfortunately, I kind of hoped to get a displayable image that way (I did not), so apparently something else is going wrong as well. Are you *sure* your input image is in fact a PNG?

Comment: By the way: the "PNG" part says it's 1656 x 2340 pixels, but this (malformed) JPEG tells me it's 1654 x 2340 pixels instead. Numbers that may or may not help you finding the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. One of the other developers managed to crack it - it was (as Jongware suggested) a JPEG, but it was actually zipped as well! Once unzipped it could be processed and recognised as normal.

Comment: Any chance to see the solution? Thanks